# What would happen if I miss the Schengen visa application appointment?

Tags: visas, switzerland, uk-residents

I have an appointment to apply for Swiss Schengen Visa, but I just figure out I missed some necessary documents. However, I can not reschedule because it is within a day.

So, what would happen if I miss the Schengen visa appointment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll still have to forfeit the fees, and would likely have to re-apply again.

For example, from the [Indian page on Schengen applications](https://www.visaservices.firm.in/SVAC-UAE-APP/AppointmentScheduling/AppWelcome.aspx?param=cGjxmtrkNVcFxUpzF79ClwzuymM6uXSaEYi28F5Ig+96V+OT+jVqi+qKr434K10L):

> Please note the service charges will be forfeited in the following
>   situations and a new appointment will have to be scheduled
>
> 1. If you miss your appointment on the scheduled date
> 2. If you are delayed for your appointment and cannot be accommodated on the same day
> 3. If your application is incomplete and the application cannot be accepted
> 4. If you cancel your appointment

Answer (score 2):

I went to VFS, but I forgot some documents, so I decided not to apply but come back with another appointment. I was not charged.

Comment: So apparently even if they *can* charge you, it doesn't mean that they *will* charge you.

Comment: @phoog honestly I have no idea :p